# Android KeyStore implementation for < 4.3

Tags: aes, android, rsa, keystore

I'm planning to use the `KeyStore` in my Android app to encrypt an AES key with a `KeyPair` that's stored inside the `KeyStore`. Android documentation for the KeyStore:

https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore.html

After searching the internet I found an AOSP example which I edited to this:

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2013 The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;
import android.security.KeyPairGeneratorSpec;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.UnrecoverableEntryException;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.security.auth.x500.X500Principal;


/**
 * Wraps {@link SecretKey} instances using a public/private key pair stored in
 * the platform {@link KeyStore}. This allows us to protect symmetric keys with
 * hardware-backed crypto, if provided by the device.
 * <p>
 * See <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_Wrap">key wrapping</a> for more
 * details.
 * <p>
 * Not inherently thread safe.
 *
 * Some explanations:
 * http://nelenkov.blogspot.nl/2013/08/credential-storage-enhancements-android-43.html
 */
public class SecretKeyWrapper {
    private final Cipher mCipher;
    private final KeyPair mPair;
    /**
     * Create a wrapper using the public/private key pair with the given alias.
     * If no pair with that alias exists, it will be generated.
     */
    public SecretKeyWrapper(Context context, String alias)
            throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
        mCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
        final KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
        keyStore.load(null);
        if (!keyStore.containsAlias(alias)) {
            generateKeyPair(context, alias);
        }
        // Even if we just generated the key, always read it back to ensure we
        // can read it successfully.
        final KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry entry = (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) keyStore.getEntry(
                alias, null);
        mPair = new KeyPair(entry.getCertificate().getPublicKey(), entry.getPrivateKey());
    }
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
    private static void generateKeyPair(Context context, String alias)
            throws GeneralSecurityException {
        final Calendar start = new GregorianCalendar();
        final Calendar end = new GregorianCalendar();
        end.add(Calendar.YEAR, 100);
        final KeyPairGeneratorSpec spec = new KeyPairGeneratorSpec.Builder(context)
                .setAlias(alias)
                .setSubject(new X500Principal("CN=" + alias))
                .setSerialNumber(BigInteger.ONE)
                .setStartDate(start.getTime())
                .setEndDate(end.getTime())
                .build();
        final KeyPairGenerator gen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", "AndroidKeyStore");
        gen.initialize(spec);
        gen.generateKeyPair();
    }

    /**
     * Wrap a {@link SecretKey} using the public key assigned to this wrapper.
     * Use {@link #unwrap(byte[])} to later recover the original
     * {@link SecretKey}.
     *
     * @return a wrapped version of the given {@link SecretKey} that can be
     *         safely stored on untrusted storage.
     */
    public byte[] wrap(SecretKey key) throws GeneralSecurityException {
        mCipher.init(Cipher.WRAP_MODE, mPair.getPublic());
        return mCipher.wrap(key);
    }
    /**
     * Unwrap a {@link SecretKey} using the private key assigned to this
     * wrapper.
     *
     * @param blob a wrapped {@link SecretKey} as previously returned by
     *            {@link #wrap(SecretKey)}.
     */
    public SecretKey unwrap(byte[] blob) throws GeneralSecurityException {
        mCipher.init(Cipher.UNWRAP_MODE, mPair.getPrivate());
        return (SecretKey) mCipher.unwrap(blob, "AES", Cipher.SECRET_KEY);
    }
}
```

This implementation kan `wrap` and `unwrap` a `SecretKey` which is in my case an AES key.

However, this KeyStore is only supported from 4.3 and onwards. See the Jelly Bean annotation.

To come to my question, what are the possibilities for a likewise implementation for below 4.3?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 7):

The keystore is available since 1.6, but there is no official API in earlier versions. You can still use it through the private API, but you might face various problems.

An example can be found on the same blog you referenced:

http://nelenkov.blogspot.com/2012/05/storing-application-secrets-in-androids.html

The implementation might end up somewhat tricky because the keystore needs to be unlocked independently from the device lockscreen. It might be better to consider password-based encryption for earlier versions, there is a post about it on the blog.

Answer (score 0):

Symmetric key generation and storage in the Android KeyStore is supported from Android 6.0 (API Level 23) onwards.

Asymmetric key generation and storage in the Android KeyStore is supported from Android 4.3 (API Level 18) onwards.

See this document for more info:
http://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore.html